# In a mysql database is it possible to find a table that would contain a specific column name?

Tags: mysql

I’m using a heavy duty CMS and have created a new data field for a certain content type. the data field is named ‘sort order’ or possibly ‘sort_order’. I’m assuming the data field is added to a table and  have no way of knowing which table it was added to. When viewing the database via phpmyadmin there are simply too many tables to go looking for it.

Is there any way possible to do a search to find which table would contain this column name? or maybe an alternate method would be some look for most recent updated table?

Comment: To find a column name you may use `SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'thename'`. However, many CMS add custom fields using key/value storage in a generic table rather than actually creating a dedicated column for the field you added -- a table with a column for the field name and a column for its value.

Comment: Without knowing the CMS specifically, it's hard to say how yours would have been created.